# Cannot connect to SQL DB with Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to connect to remote SQL server. **I do connect from SQL Management Studio** without problems, but with the code below i wait like 2-3 mins to get error `ECONNRESET`, what's wrong? Why do I wait so much?

```
let mysql = require('mysql'),
   express = require('express'),
   bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
   app = new express(),
   _port = process.env.port || 3000; 

let con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '***.***.***.***',
    port: ****,
    user: "*****",
    password: "****"
});

con.connect( function (err) {
   if (err) console.log(err);
   console.log('connected');
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send('ffs');
});

app.listen(_port, () => {
   console.log('listening on port ' + _port);
});
```

The `mysql` version is `2.11.0` atm, but i tried with the latest one first.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for running MySQL version `2.11.0` and why did you tag `sql-server`?

Comment: Which version of mysql NPM package are you using ?

Comment: @PeterM No, I just wanted to be sure that is not related to the version problems. `Sparw` Happy now?

Comment: And which port are you using ? :)

Comment: The port which the servers uses.

Comment: To get more information, maybe you should try with "debug:true" option..

Comment: @Denisx or try running it with [--abort-on-uncaught-exception](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_abort_on_uncaught_exception) this should give you some more info.